# Getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException while I am using SpEL

Tags: java, spring

I am facing one issue during invocation of a particular service. I am getting

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'com.test.Adult@459ca355' is defined

I am loading this bean using SpEL :

```
<bean id="mainClass" class="com.test.MainClass">
  <property name="prop" ref="#{testBean.isAdult()=='T'?adult:child}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="adult" class="com.test.Adult">
  <property name="name" value="John"/>
</bean>
<bean id="child" class="com.test.Child">
  <property name="name" value="Smith"/>
</bean>
```

Above mentioned condition - `testBean.isAdult()` is working. Because if its true its throwing 
following exception

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'com.test.**Adult**@459ca355' is defined

else its throwing :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'com.test.**Child**@459ca355' is defined

But I am concerned with `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. Please help me if you have any idea about this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep adult and child in single quotes. See below configuration

```
<bean id="mainClass" class="com.test.MainClass">
  <property name="prop" ref="#{testBean.isAdult()=='T'?'adult':'child'}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="adult" class="com.test.Adult">
  <property name="name" value="John"/>
</bean>
<bean id="child" class="com.test.Child">
  <property name="name" value="Smith"/>
</bean>
```